# Java Reading a txt file

Tags: java, arrays, file, io

I am in the middle of a coding experiment, and generally everything has went smoothly until this very last part. I really have no idea where to even begin with this sub question, and it's really stressing me out like you cant believe. I've tried way after way only getting errors. And it's a real downer because everything before it and pretty much after it went well. It's just I have no idea where to begin, and even after reading some tutorials, I am still having some major trouble with getting it to work right.

Basically, I have to read this txt file, ( http://www.mediafire.com/?a6d7c0c5cdu1gup )
and put the data into 5 arrays (without a scanner)

The Name has to go into the Name array, the N/Y has to go into the Before array, the next column of numbers have to go into into the timespent array, the next column has to go into the assistants array and the last row has to go into the risk array.

So we have 5 Arrays

```
String Name [] = new String [20)

Char Before [] = new Char [20]

Int timeSpent [] = new Int [20]

Int Assistants [] = new int [20]

Double Risk [] = new Double [20]
```

So these are your 5 arrays that i've made, but what I am having trouble with is reading the text file and writing it so that the appropriate column goes into the appropriate array.

So any help with getting my code together and those values into there proper respective arrays so that I can continue would be very, very greatly appreciated. Thanks alot.

Comment: Do you really have to use 5 arrays? It would be *far* cleaner to have one array (or a `List`) of a user-defined type with all the details of a person in.

Comment: It is advisable to place your future text pastes into one of the code bin sites.

Comment: Please paste some (abbreviated) lines of the txt file instead of linking to mediafire... Anyway you could read each line and use the  "split" method to parse it, I'm guessing, I won't open that mediafire link :)

Answer (score 3):

Use BufferedReader for getting line by line and split using regex

```
  File file = new File("1.txt");
  FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
  String line;
  while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
      String[] record = line.split(",\\s*");  
      // record[0] contain name
      // record[1] contain N/Y etc.. 
      //* code here 

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml) example which shows how you can traverse a file without using the `Scanner` class. One you have read the line, you can use the [`.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the line into tokens. Since all the sections are divided by comma, you can use the following piece of code: `line.split(",");`, where `line` denotes the line you have just read from the file.

The `split` function yields an array, so you can traverse it and put the data in the correct array of your choice.

The above should do what you need. You can, however, take a look at [JavaCSV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) which should also help you do what you need:

> Java CSV is a small fast open source java library for reading and
>   writing CSV and plain delimited text files.